my setState icon boutton can't work in flutter(solved)
Hello i'm try to change to color of my IconBouttom that is inside setState each time he is clicked but it's not changing
I tried to put the iconbouttom outside the positioned widget and it worket so the probleme is because of the postioned widget but i don't know how to fix it   , i have also tried to change  the location of my bool LikeIt location but it did not work
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icon.dart';

class Categoriespecifiqueitem extends StatefulWidget {
  const Categoriespecifiqueitem({super.key});

  @override
  State<Categoriespecifiqueitem> createState() =>
      _CategoriespecifiqueitemState();
}

bool _isSearchBarTapped = true;

// i tried declaration here bool likeIt = false;

class _CategoriespecifiqueitemState extends State<Categoriespecifiqueitem> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
// i tried declaration here   bool likeIt = false;

  var MylistImage = [
    "images/clothes/chemise.jpg",
    "images/clothes/suit.jpg",
    "images/clothes/hat.jpg",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var values = RangeValues(10, 250);
// i tried declaration here     bool likeIt = false;

    return Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF1F1F1),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _isSearchBarTapped = false;
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "iphone",
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                          prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isSearchBarTapped = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: const LineIcon.arrowLeft()),
                          suffixIcon: const LineIcon.search()),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (_isSearchBarTapped == false) ...[
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 10),
                            title: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("iphone XS"),
                                Divider(
                                  thickness: 2,
                                )
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    ))
                  ],
                  if (_isSearchBarTapped == true) ...[
                    Gap(20),
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    likeIt = !likeIt;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: likeIt == false
                                    ? LineIcon.heart()
                                    : LineIcon.heartAlt(
                                        color: Colors.pink,
                                      )),
                          ),
                          Swiper(
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Image.asset(
                                MylistImage[index],
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: 3,
                            pagination: SwiperPagination(),
                            control: SwiperControl(color: Colors.cyan),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 0.1),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                  ]
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
}
//


So the probleme was because of The stack Widget and since the swiper was above the HeartIcon i wasn't able to click on it ,The solution Was just to make the icon above the swiper and move the postioned widget down the swiper , thanks everyone and sorry for disturbance

You should not re-declare likeIt variable inside build. The likeIt changes because of the setState but its redeclared in the build method to false because your widget is rebuilt everytime setState is called.

Still not Working  i just redeclared it to show you that i have tried to declare it at those positions

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icon.dart';

class Categoriespecifiqueitem extends StatefulWidget {
  const Categoriespecifiqueitem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoriespecifiqueitemState createState() =>
      _CategoriespecifiqueitemState();
}

class _CategoriespecifiqueitemState extends State<Categoriespecifiqueitem> {
  bool likeIt = false; // Initialize likeIt state

  var MylistImage = [
    "images/clothes/chemise.jpg",
    "images/clothes/suit.jpg",
    "images/clothes/hat.jpg",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF1F1F1),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      // your code
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "iphone",
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // your code
                        });
                      },
                      child: const LineIcon.arrowLeft(),
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: const LineIcon.search(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (_isSearchBarTapped == false) ...[
                // Render content if search bar is not tapped
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 10),
                        title: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("iphone XS"),
                            Divider(
                              thickness: 2,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              if (_isSearchBarTapped == true) ...[
                // Render content if search bar is tapped
                Gap(20),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        top: 8, // Adjust positioning as needed
                        right: 8,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              likeIt = !likeIt; // Toggle likeIt state
                            });
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            likeIt ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                            color: likeIt ? Colors.pink : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Swiper(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Image.asset(
                            MylistImage[index],
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: 3,
                        pagination: SwiperPagination(),
                        control: SwiperControl(color: Colors.cyan),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 0.1),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                                Text("data"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


not working  i also didn't understand what modification did you maked

You should declare likeIt inside state class. I tried to reproduce your problem, but without some parts of your code which I haven't got - and it's work.
This is code which I tested:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icon.dart';

final class Categoriespecifiqueitem extends StatefulWidget {
  ///
  const Categoriespecifiqueitem({super.key});

  @override
  State<Categoriespecifiqueitem> createState() =>
      _CategoriespecifiqueitemState();
}

bool _isSearchBarTapped = true;

class _CategoriespecifiqueitemState extends State<Categoriespecifiqueitem> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool likeIt = false;

  var MylistImage = [
    "images/clothes/chemise.jpg",
    "images/clothes/suit.jpg",
    "images/clothes/hat.jpg",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var values = RangeValues(10, 250);
// i tried declaration here     bool likeIt = false;

    return Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF1F1F1),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _isSearchBarTapped = false;
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "iphone",
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                          prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isSearchBarTapped = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: const LineIcon.arrowLeft()),
                          suffixIcon: const LineIcon.search()),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (_isSearchBarTapped == false) ...[
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 10),
                            title: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("iphone XS"),
                                Divider(
                                  thickness: 2,
                                )
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    ))
                  ],
                  if (_isSearchBarTapped == true) ...[
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    likeIt = !likeIt;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: likeIt == false
                                    ? LineIcon.heart()
                                    : LineIcon.heartAlt(
                                        color: Colors.pink,
                                      )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 0.1),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                  Text("data"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                  ]
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }
}


So I only added likeIt declaration after _key and removed Gap with Swiper because I don't have it.

If you can not make your code working, I recommend to make decoposition - it's better to use several small widgets instead of large one. It also would be easy to localize and fix happened errors.
